# Inject css file with proxied browsersync

Tags: javascript, npm, browser-sync

I have a script I use to proxy a live website so I can work on it's css.  It works by replacing online css file with local css file with a rewrite.

This isn't ideal.  It would be much better if I could inject a completely new file below their file.

Is it possible to modify this script so that it adds the css file instead of re-writing it.

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

browserSync({
  proxy: 'http://example.com/',
  files: ['build/**'],
  serveStatic: ['build'],
  rewriteRules: [
      {
        match: new RegExp('/css/example.css'),
        fn: function() {
          return '/my.css';
        }
      }
  ]
});
```

So basically I want to add my.css below example.css instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by replacing closing tag:

```
match: new RegExp('<\/head>'),
        fn: function() {
          return '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/test.css" media="all" /></head>';
        },
```